# Automatically change to nobody and nogroup after deleting a user

Tags: permissions, users, groups

I'm currently working on a Ubuntu 20. I have one file owned by the user "usertest" and group "grouptest"  (UID=1002 | GID=1003).

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 usertest grouptest    0 Jun 29 14:00 noG.txt
```

If I want to delete the group "grouptest", this file owned by group "grouptest" will have the group id instead of the group name.

```
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 usertest     1003    0 Jun 29 14:00 noG.txt
```

For now, it's ok. But if I add another user (usetest2) all files with the GID=1003 will be owned by the default group of user "usertest2". Because of the next ID  Which I think it's not the best idea.

```
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 usertest usertest2    0 Jun 29 14:00 noG.txt
```

For this problem momentarily I know 3 solutions:

1. Delete that user and after that search in system for files with UID=X and change permission like I want.
2. Make a script that deletes the user and find automatically all files.
3. Delete all files of that user when the user is deleted.

The question is:

- Can I delete a user/group and all files owned by that user/group to be owned by nobody/nogroup (automatically)?

Comment: A sloppy solution would be along the lines of `sudo find / -user $deleteduser -exec chown nobody:nogroup {} +` ... sloppy for two reasons: it only checks owner, not group (checking both would miss all items owned by `$deleteduser` but a group different from the default group of said user) and the `{} +` would require the GNU flavor of `find`, I believe. The latter can be worked around by using `xargs`, though.

Answer (score 1):

*"Can I delete a user/group and all files owned by that user/group to be owned by nouser/nogroup (automatically)?"*

I would say: yes, you can: by the way you propose yourself, a script that removes the user and/or group, and then takes action as you like (change uid/gid, or delete the siles) on the files owned by this user/group. `find` can recursively locate files having a specific uid and gid.

If you are looking for an option build into the standard tools for user management: it is possible to automatically have the user's home folder removed when removing the user. If you want something else, you need to automate it through a script.